# Cómo Validar Campos de contraseña en JAVA para aceptar caracteres especiales

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Soy un poco nuevo en JAVA y Tengo que crear los usuarios de una aplicación que estoy iniciando. Tengo un formulario para crear cada usuario, en el cual tengo dos campos: usuario y contraseña.
El detalle es que necesito verificar que en el campo contraseña el usuario haya introducido una contraseña que tenga al menos dos números, dos caracteres especiales(como %&$#@?¿¡!_-) y por supuesto letras. 
Existe algun script que permita Comprobar que la contraseña insertada reúna estas especificaciones antes de guardarla en base de datos y crear el nuevo usuario ?

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar ese tipo de validaciones puedes utilizar expresiones regular[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
en java.

Ejemplo

```
   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]");

   System.out.println(regex.matcher("Hola+").find());
```